# MATLAB: repeat row vector in multiple dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create multidimensional arrays that repeat a vector along along the other dimensions. E.g. for row-vectors `a` and `b` I can create `A` which has `A(:,n,m,k)=a` for all `n`,`m`,`k` and similarly `B` which has `B(n,:,m,k)` for all `n`,`m`,`k` as follows:

`A=repmat(a', [1 length(b) length(c) length(d)]);
B=repmat(b, [length(a) 1 length(c) length(d)]);`

How can I do the equivalent for C and D? I.e. such that C(n,m,:,k)=c where c is a row vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself, one can use the permute function, e.g.:

`B=repmat(b, [length(x) 1 length(a) length(c)]);
B=permute(B,[1 3 2 4]);`